# pgfplots bar plot: add labeled arrow from one bar to another

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a pgfplots chart looking like this.

```latex
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        bar width=1.5cm,
        x=3cm,
        enlarge x limits={abs=1.5cm},
        enlarge y limits=false,
        ymin=0,
        nodes near coords,
        xtick=data,
        ylabel=Returns,
        symbolic x coords={Then, Now},
        axis lines*=left,
        clip=false
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {(Then,3) (Now,9)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to add the red parts to it, that is, an arrow from one bar to the next, with a label. This picture isn't an exact requirement and the label is perfectly fine if not auto-generated or placed somewhere else on the arrow.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a method if you want easily and precisely place the arrow. You could put the `\draw` inside the `axis` environment and use `axis cs` and `[normalized]` location for the symbolic coordinates where `[normalized]0` will be the `Then` coordinate and `[normalized]1` will be the `Now` coordinate. Then you could shift the these coordinates using `xshift` and `yshift` according to your needs and the bar width probably.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        bar width=1.5cm,
        x=3cm,
        enlarge x limits={abs=1.5cm},
        enlarge y limits=false,
        ymin=0,
        nodes near coords,
        xtick=data,
        ylabel=Returns,
        symbolic x coords={Then, Now},
        axis lines*=left,
        clip=false
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {(Then,3) (Now,9)};
        \draw[->,red,thick] ([xshift=0.75cm]axis cs:{[normalized]0},3) -- ([xshift=-0.75cm]axis cs:{[normalized]1},9) node[above,midway,sloped] {+200\%};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a quick hack, you could manually add the arrow (adjust the coordinates as needed):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        bar width=1.5cm,
        x=3cm,
        enlarge x limits={abs=1.5cm},
        enlarge y limits=false,
        ymin=0,
        nodes near coords,
        xtick=data,
        ylabel=Returns,
        symbolic x coords={Then, Now},
        axis lines*=left,
        clip=false
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {(Then,3) (Now,9)};
    \end{axis}
    \draw[->,red,thick] (2,2) -- (3,5) node[midway,anchor=east] {+200\%};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]